# Facebook like button is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have 2 sites where Facebook like button is not working:

http://www.mantrazdrowia.pl/przepisy/slodkosci/sernik-truskawkowy/ - I would like to like that url (tried to like it even from FB code generator - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - no success) despite that its homepage: http://www.mantrazdrowia.pl/ can be liked just fine

and same applies here: http://www.shopperhive.co.uk/blog and http://www.shopperhive.co.uk/  any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go here, you should see list of problems:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mantrazdrowia.pl%2Fprzepisy%2Fslodkosci%2Fsernik-truskawkowy%2F

```
Required Property Missing   og:title is required
Required Property Missing   og:type is required
Required Property Missing   og:url is required
Required Property Missing   og:image is required</tr>
```

Comment: yep, the og:image now supports only absolute path and that was the issue

Comment: you have no og:image there. so how ?

Comment: I had but with not absolute path but relative which doesn't work anymore, probably if I would have at all all would work.

Comment: But i have more like buttons on single page... for which how to give specific meta title, image and url...