# Facebook like count linter

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I integrated facebook like button on my site for multiple posts.When I click without the linting the url it does not save the count, it shows only 1 and the count get disappear, but when i lint the url and like the post it works great. I am already installed share bar plugin for single posts,but i want to also display like on multiple posts so I added new facebook like button code for multiple posts. Why it is not saving facebook like count without linting?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: [Facebook like button is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642749/facebook-like-button-is-not-working/6643423#6643423)

> If you go here, you should see list of problems:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mantrazdrowia.pl%2Fprzepisy%2Fslodkosci%2Fsernik-truskawkowy%2F

```
Required Property Missing   og:title is required
Required Property Missing   og:type is required
Required Property Missing   og:url is required
Required Property Missing   og:image is required
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not mentioned that I am using iframe facebook like button

Comment: exactly same as mentioned in that tool ?

Comment: yes the same code from lint, i am just added layout parameter to it, because i want it like a button